# Data can not be appears, database relation one to one Laravel

Tags: laravel

> ErrorException
> **Trying to get property 'category_name' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\e-catalog\resources\views\backend\pages\gmproducts.blade.php)**

This is my blade code below.

```
<tbody>
 @foreach($gmproducts as $no => $gm)
 <tr>
  <td>{{$no+1}}</td>
  <td>{{$gm->type}}</td>
  <td>{{$gm->gmcategories->category_name}}</td>
  <td>{{$gm->gram}}</td>
  <td>{{$gm->carat}}</td>
  <td>@currency($gm->price)</td>
  <td><a class="test-popup-link" href="{{url('p_goldmart/'.$gm->file)}}">Preview</a></td>
  <td>
   <a href="/gmproducts/update/{{$gm->id}}" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
   <a href="/gmproducts/delete/{{$gm->id}}" class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
</tbody>
```

This is my model Gmcategories & Gmproducts.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gmcategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = "gmcategories";
    protected $fillable = ['category_name'];

    public function gmproducts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Gmproducts');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Gmproducts extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "gmproducts";
    protected $fillable = ['type', 'category_id', 'gram', 'carat', 'price', 'file'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function gmcategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Gmcategories');
    }
}
```

This is my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Gmproducts;
use App\Gmcategories;
use File;

class GmproductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $gmproducts   = Gmproducts::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        $trash      = Gmproducts::orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')->onlyTrashed()->count();
        return view('backend.pages.gmproducts', compact('gmproducts', 'trash'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $gmcategories   = Gmcategories::all();
        return view('backend.pages.create', compact('gmcategories'));
    }
```

Just info, I just rename my model and controller. Does it have any effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Gmcategories model
public function gmproducts()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Gmproducts', 'category_id');
}

// Gmproducts model
public function gmcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Gmcategories', 'category_id');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work! I have model with relationship one to one database.

Comment: You have not apply proper relationship. I updated my answer. Check it out

Comment: you may need to clear the cache php artisan cache:clear or  php artisan optimize:clear

Answer (score -1):

> Your BuildImage model should be
>
> Get the source type of the Building Image.

```
public function type() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\BuildingType',"id","source"); 
}
```

> And BuildingType Model should be
>
> Get the Building Image that owns the building type.

```
public function buildingImage()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\BuildingImage',"source","id");
}
```

Comment: sorry i write something wrong please check once it's working or not @My Buzynis